# Create a table based on few columns of another table, but also add some additional columns

Tags: mysql

I know I can do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS (
    SELECT field1, field2, field3
    FROM my_table
)
```

I'm wondering how do I add more columns to this create table `SQL`, that are not from `my_table`, but instead ones that I would write my self and which would be unique to this `new_table` only.

I know I could just make the table with the above `SQL` and then additionaly (after the command is completed) add the necessary columns, but am wondering if this all could be done in one command, maybe something like this (tried it like that, but didn't work):

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS (
    (SELECT field1, field2, field3
    FROM my_table),
    additional_field1 INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    additional_field2 VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
)
```

Comment: Do you want empty table new_table with this structure?

Comment: no, I don't want an empty table, i wan't the table to be populated with the fields from the table `my_table` and additionaly I want to add my fields which, will be default to some value (just added `DEFAULT` to my sql example above)

Comment: Updated answer should work for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also explicitly specify the data type for a generated column:

See [Create Table Select Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-select.html)

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
(
 additional_field1 INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
 additional_field2 VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
)
AS
(
 SELECT id, val,
        1 AS additional_field1,
        1 AS additional_field2
 FROM my_table
);
```

## Example: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5eea5/1)